# Google Sheets: Add value to total if a row condition matches for infinite column

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to make a Google Sheet that has a column for a rate and a value of that rate.  Each night I am adding a new value to the bottom of this list so I want it to continue as an infinite list.  What this sheet should do is look down the list of rates, if the rate matches a predefined rate, it should add the corresponding value to the total for that rate.  I have four common rates that occur in no particular order and with some given value.  I would like to total the values for each of those rates and give them in the totals section so each rate can be easily referenced.

Is there a way to do this using Google Sheets built-in commands?  Pseudocode would be something like IF(A2:A = rate, add value in B to total).  I know to make an infinite reading of a column by A2:A, but I don't know how to check each value as it goes through that column.  I have attached a test spreadsheet with some sample values and the output that should be given by the formula.  Thank you in advance for your help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19k1DMipSsI9tWSjTXrVAPzPoaenWS6WYmlwe201_WQk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I managed to discover my own answer using the SUMIF statement.  My code for the rate of .75 is ""=SUMIF(A2:A,"=.75",B2:B)"".  I ran into some more trouble with the section for a different rate because I was having trouble saying not equal to .75 or 1 or 1.5 or 1.75.  I solved this problem by completely bypassing it and adding the all the values and subtracting away the values already added.  I would still like to know how to give the list of "ors" if someone could shed some light on this.  But I now have a working solution regardless.  I have updated the test sheet to show the solution.